# Where can one find online the 15 tithi khadagmalas which are chanted as per tithi?

Tags: resource, stotra, sri-vidya

Looking for Tithi Khadagmalas (15 Khadagmalas for the 15 Nitya Devis corresponding to the lunar dates) possibly with explanation.

Where online we can find these 15 versions of Khadgamala?

Comment: @rickross you must be aware of 15 khadagmala for each nitya. Each mala is chanted as per date.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the specifics of Sri Vidya are kept secret. Khadgamala is not merely a Stotra or a hymn but is a Mala Mantra which invokes Sri Mahatripurasundari along with all her Avarana Devatas. It is a very powerful invocation. I doubt they are freely available on the Internet. However I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes but i instead posted an answer which gave the info on which Nitya Devis are to be worshipped on which Tithis. @Saurabh  So, i have deleted the answer. You can't see deleted answers right now. Once u get to 2000 Rep points u'll be able to see them.

Comment: Is it about tithi nityas